# MySQL Trigger Nested Group_Concat Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger to conditionally GROUP_CONCAT a few columns. I can remove duplicates from within a single column, but I’m struggling to remove duplicates between two or more columns.

Current trigger (two column example):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
set NEW.results =
(SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(distinct (CONCAT_WS('<br>',
(SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(distinct stocks1 SEPARATOR '<br>'))
FROM Table2
where NEW.selection1 = 'x'),
(SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(distinct stocks2 SEPARATOR '<br>'))
FROM Table2
where NEW.selection2 = 'x')
)))));
end;
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46a6bb915fa7e2e9106b073677eee6cd

Comment: can you please explain in more words what you want to get, the sample really doesn't clear it up

Comment: @nbk. I want to join the two columns into one row without duplicates. In my fiddle it will remove duplicates for a single column, stocks1 or stocks2, but not between stocks1 and stock2. If stocks1 and stocks2 both had ‘BRK’, I would only want to see it once in the results, not twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second Select to

> ```
> -- Table1
>
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT,selection1 varchar(50),selection2 varchar(50),results varchar(1000));
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 (id,selection1,selection2,results) 
> VALUES
> (1,null,null,null),
> (2,null,null,null),
> (3,null,null,null);
>
> select * from Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | selection1 | selection2 | results
> -: | :--------- | :--------- | :------
>  1 | null       | null       | null   
>  2 | null       | null       | null   
>  3 | null       | null       | null
> ```

> ```
> -- Table2
>
> CREATE TABLE Table2 (stocks1 VARCHAR(50),stocks2 VARCHAR(50));
>
> INSERT INTO Table2 (stocks1,stocks2) 
> VALUES
> -- ('BRK','BRK'),
> -- ('BRK','BRK');
>
> ('BRK','GOOG'),
> ('INTC','NKE'),
> ('TSLA','APPL'),
> ('APPL','NKE'),
> ('TSLA','FB'),
> ('NKE','BRK');
>
>
> select * from Table2
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> stocks1 | stocks2
> :------ | :------
> BRK     | GOOG   
> INTC    | NKE    
> TSLA    | APPL   
> APPL    | NKE    
> TSLA    | FB     
> NKE     | BRK
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
> BEFORE UPDATE
> ON Table1
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> set NEW.results =
> (SELECT CONCAT('<br>',GROUP_CONCAT( val
>                                 SEPARATOR '<br>'))
> FROM (SELECT stocks1 as val FROM                    
>                         Table2
>                     WHERE
>                         NEW.selection2 = 'x'
>     UNION
>        SELECT stocks2 FROM                    
>                         Table2
>                     WHERE
>                         NEW.selection2 = 'x') t1
> );
> end;
> ```

> ```
> update Table1
> set selection1 = 'x', selection2 = 'x'
> where id = 1
> ```

> ```
> select * from Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | selection1 | selection2 | results                                             
> -: | :--------- | :--------- | :---------------------------------------------------
>  1 | x          | x          | <br>BRK<br>INTC<br>TSLA<br>APPL<br>NKE<br>GOOG<br>FB
>  2 | null       | null       | null                                                
>  3 | null       | null       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f41d5d4069854f513386b79216ef379c)*

Comment: That works. If there were more columns I guess I just have to keep adding comparisons?

Comment: yeah i thought about more columns, and would write a IN (SELECT stocks1...UNION SELECT stocks2 ....)  for all other columns that should keep the code simple

Comment: Do you have an example of what that would look like?

Comment: sure https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ed05f6413d2dcde89e25e4440c0496c

Comment: That’s great! Thanks!

Comment: I’ve been playing around with the comparison version and it appears to not be working correctly for different values in Table2. In the fiddle below I’ve changed the values in Table2 and there are multiple duplicates. See fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4fbb0611538edf8436c241dc3012cb8

Comment: i rewrote the answer, now they are unique, but the order is as you should know unsorted

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate it.